# Function execution took 60060 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'. Google cloud functions

Tags: javascript, express, google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to upload my nodejs work on googlecloud functions but i am getting timeout error in logs. I am trying to load the homepage using templates. I am unable to use the helloworld function properly. Below is a part of the code and not a complete code.

```
exports.helloworld = ()=>{
    app.get('/',(req, res)=> {
        res.render('home');
    });
}

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('app now listening for requests on port 3000');
});
```

Comment: Cloud Functions does not support writing code that listens on ports.  Cloud Functions manages the sockets, and you just write trigger code.  I suggest going back to the documentation and following its examples.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use express js routing in the cloud functions, you need to export the express js app instead of running the server.

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.get('/',(req, res)=> {
    res.render('home');
});
app.get('/login',(req, res)=> {
    res.render('login');
});
exports.helloworld = app;
```